# trouble checking for overlap in a 2-D array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble with a part of a program that takes a dynamically allocated object called userRect and checks for it overlapping on an array of chars arranged in the shape of a rectangle. The other rectangles rect[0] and rect[1] are randomly placed on a imaginary grid in a console window.

rect[0] prints out with '0'
rect[1] prints out with '1'
userRect prints out with '#' if no overlap is present.
userRect prints out with '+' at each char in the array that is overlapping another object.

The object userRect is movable with the w,a,s,d keys.
What is supposed to happen is when the user moves the userRect object and it overlaps another rect object. Each character that overlaps is replaced with a '+'.

The program is not printing a '+' when  the userRect is overlapping another rectangle. Can anyone point out what is causing this?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    bool isOverlapping(Rect const & r) const
    {
        return !(min.x >= r.max.x || max.x <= r.min.x
            || min.y >= r.max.y || max.y <= r.min.y);
    }


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    // initialization
    Rect * userRect;
    const int rectSize = 5;
    Rect rect[rectSize];
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 13;  // size of userRect
    userRect = new Rect();

    // set
    rect[0].setRandom(rect[0]);
    rect[1].setRandomByPointer(& rect[1]);
    userRect->setMin(7, 5);
    userRect->setMax(10, 9);
    //rect0.setMin(10, 2);
    //rect0.setMax(14, 4);
    //rect1.setMin(1, 6);
    //rect1.setMax(5, 15);
    int userInput;

    do
    {
        // draw
        rect[0].draw('0');
        rect[1].draw('1');  
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (userRect->isOverlapping(rect[i]))
            {
                userRect->draw('+');
            }
            else userRect->draw('#');
        }
```

Comment: I don't see an actual question in here. Also, you may want to compact this into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Your development environment almost certainly [has a debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger). The sooner you get good at using it, the more productive a programmer you will be.

Comment: I am using the debugger and from what I can tell userRect->isOverlapping(rect[i]) is passing each rect[i] object into the function and checking to see if  min.x >= r.max.x || max.x <= r.min.x
            || min.y >= r.max.y || max.y <= r.min.y  are true and the returning the opposite. My question is wouldn't this cause a bug because if one of those returned a true and the other returned a false (meaning one is of the chars is overlapping) the result would still return the wrong bool resulting in bool isOverlapping always returning false.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is shouldn't I test for each possible case separately and return a result instead of lumping them together with the || operator?

Comment: I have attempted to edit out most of the irrelevant code from the program. I hope it is easier to read and understand what the code is accomplishing.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was wrong. The problem was in my for loop. If the userRect was within the boundaries of the rect[0] but not within the bounds of rect[1] the `userRect->draw('#');` would overwrite the `userRect->draw('+');` operation that was just executed before it. Thank you guys for all the help.